# How filter an http response with MailChimp API V3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

How filter a http response with MailChimp API V3 ?
I'm working in NodeJS. I'm trying to filter the response of my "GET" request in MailChimp API.

​

Here my snippet.js :

​

```
var getList ="https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/6b3d443365/members"  

request({
    url: getList,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey ' + password
    },
    fields: ["id"], // I have also tried: "Fields"
}, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("err:", err)
    }
    console.log("connection succeed");
    console.log("res: ", body)
});
```

​

I have tried also :

​

1-

```
fields:["members.id", "members.email_adress"]
```

​

2-

```
fields:"id"
```

​

> res : `BIG BUNCH of data`

​

all my tentative fails, my console returns me a big bunch with all the data in. I want to filter it but I don't have a clue how to make it. The documentation affirm :

​

> *Query string parameters*
>
> fields:
>
> Type: Array
>
> Title: Fields
>
> Read only: false
>
> A comma-separated list of fields to return. Reference parameters of
>   sub-objects with dot notation.

It seems to me I have followed the notice, so, what's going wrong ?

Comment: works a little better with `json: { Fields:[ "email_address"]}` but doesn't filters anything again, whatever I enter in the array the result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation does in fact say that the 'fields' parameter is

> A comma-separated list of fields to return. Reference parameters of
>   sub-objects with dot notation.

https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/automation/

The key information that is missing is that you need to prefix each field with a (redundant) reference to the root object.

```
/3.0/automations?fields=automations.id,automations.settings.title
```

Answer (score 4):

Getting specific fields from a query (lists) I had to do the following:

```
/3.0/lists?count=100&fields=lists.name,lists.id
```

I agree with the above comment. The Mailchimp API has HORRIBLE documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a bit stale, but for the benefit of others who might find this helpful...

The Mailchimp API docs suck when it comes to examples for requests with query strings. I'm not using nodejs but PHP and Curl and was having a similar problem specifying the exact fields that I wanted returned from the API.

After many hours of trial and error I found that the ONLY query string format that works is simply: `fields=fieldname1,fieldname2,etc.`  I tried `fields=fieldname1&fields=fieldname2` and (PHP specific) `fields[]=fieldname1&fields[]=fieldname2` and `fields=[fieldname1,fieldname2]` and `fields={fieldname1,fieldname2}`.  None of the other formats worked.

Comment: a while since I have made this trial but the answer is very simple in fact, there is only one root element with subobject, and you should choose what you seek for inside the ramification from the root, for example: list.prop1.prop.2 etc.
A simple mean to find it is to console.log the root object then track where is the infoyou seek for, hope this help and thanks to provide an answer on the topic

Answer (score 1):

I agree. Terrible docs.
Here is how I filtered for only the email field returned:

?fields='members.email_address'